# Send PHP success/error message to Javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to output success & error messages after somebody submit's a form.

Here's how the form works:

Somebody can edit their post by clicking the edit button and the `<div>` box that contains the text they want to edit turns into a `<textarea>` box with "save" & "cancel" buttons.

When they click "save" it needs to output either a success message "Post has been updated", or an error message which can be a few things:

- "You can not edit this post" - If they don't have permission to edit
  the post
- "Error while selecting from database. Please try again later" - If
  the post doesn't exist
- "Please enter a post with 4 or more characters" - Post doesn't have
  enough characters

Test Page: http://thebulb.daysofthedead.net/testing.php

Javascript:

```
function sendAjax(textarea_value, post_id, blog_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'testing.php?action=blog_edit&post_id='+post_id,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            postcontent: textarea_value,
            blog_id: blog_id,
            AddReplyForm: 'Post'
        },
        success: function (answer) {
            // Should output: "<div class="dialoginfo"><div class="dialoginfosub"><div class="dialoginfocontent">Post has been updated</div></div></div>"
        },
        error: function () {
            // In the PHP script I check for:
            //     If that user has permission to edit the post. If not, it returns "You can not edit this post".
            //     If the post_id exists in the database, if not, it returns "Error while selecting from database. Please try again later".
            //     If there was 4 or more characters. If not, it returns "Please enter a post with 4 or more characters".
        }
    });
}
```

PHP (long script which is why I am using PasteBin): http://pastebin.com/za2NFPHU

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/zsWBv/12/

**EDIT:** The code all works, I just need to output the message.

For example, if I edit the post and only insert two characters and submit it, it should give an error "Please enter a post with 4 or more characters". Instead it changes the text in the `<div>`, until you refresh the page, then it goes back to the text it previously was.

The change doesn't save in the database because of the error.

If you look at the Test page, which I linked above, you can see what it does better than me explaining it. Just edit a post and save it. Try entering two characters into the box, click save. You'll see the text changed to your edit, but then refresh the page and it will revert back to what it was previously.

Comment: What specific piece of this are you having trouble with? Do you need help writing code to do the commented pieces, is the code you have not working, etc? I'm just a little confused.

Comment: What is your query? Are you asking for the code for success and error events?

Comment: @PatrickHulce The code all works, I just need to output the message. For example, if I edit the post and only insert two characters and submit it, it should give an error "Please enter a post with 4 or more characters". What it DOES do is change the text, until you refresh the page. The change doesn't save in the database because of the error. If you look at the Test page, which I linked above, you can see what it does better than me explaining it.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar Yes, I am looking for somebody help me with code that shows how I can accomplish my question.

Answer (score 0):

Display your error and success message from your php file, because you are on the wrong way of checking it with js.

From manual: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> success
>   Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

Answer (score 0):

You really should separate your giant viewBlog function into smaller logical parts, but here's what you can do to get the general effect you want now.

#### PHP

```
$response = array("status" => isset($error) ? "error" : "success",
    "msg" => $response_msg // determine this as you currently do
    );
return json_encode($response);
```

#### JS

```
$.ajax({ ...
    success : function(response) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(response);
        if(data.status == "error") { alert(data.msg); }
        else { 
            //do your success thing 
            $(".my_success_holder_div").html('<div class="dialoginfo"><div class="dialoginfosub"><div class="dialoginfocontent">Post has been updated</div></div></div>');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure how I can get that to work with my code. I am very terrible with Javascript, just can't get my head around it. I tried this: http://pastebin.com/2JEKC9BP - I know I should cut of my methods into smaller parts, but I use this style of coding on certain sites to make it easier for them to expand on. I have a MUCH larger framework I've been working on for 3 years that's coded much better.

Comment: You're close with the link, but you can't `.=` an array. Build a `$msg` variable and set the `$response` array at the end. Once you can test successfully with manually navigating to that page (no AJAX) and see a JSON response, then try the JS above. If you're having trouble understanding what the JavaScript does, do some general research on using jQuery. This question is not the place for explaining JS in general :)

Comment: Wow, can't believe I completely missed that. I took out the concatenation (.) for now. I also put a `console.log(response);` in the script and it's returning the `json` data and all the HTML from the page which is why I think it's not working now. I guess I don't know how to return the `json_encode($response);` because I have a `return` at the bottom of the method already. http://pastebin.com/2JEKC9BP

Comment: This is why separate methods are your friend. You shouldn't have everything going through a single page/method like this precisely because you run into issues and headaches later on. If you're not already familiar with [MVC](http://cakephp.org/) [design](http://framework.zend.com/) patterns, I highly suggest you look into it. You'll end up with something like `/post/view` for your actual page and `/post/update`. When these are separate pages you can freely return your json in the update AJAX view without any worries.

Comment: i do exactly this but i thought it was bandaid code, i thought there was a better way but if someone else suggests this, why not